# is it referring to a model or controller or a table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have this

```
class JobsController extends EncoderAppController
{


    var $uses = array('Cars.Engine','Trucks', 'TruckModel', 'Cars.Properties' , 'Customer', 'User');
```

I am confused as later in the code its used like this

```
$this->Trucks->
or
$this->Cars->
```

I am not sure where to look when I get to this part of the code.
thanks

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to put all (a lot) of your models in the `$uses` array. You can access all the data you need via containable behaviour, or [model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->Truck->` refers to a model. Note that Models should be singular.